# Confused with symlinks - link created within a desired directory

Tags: symlink

during installation of the program, following window popped up:
[image]

I continued with the installation and now I want to make symlink.

The reason for this is that there is plenty of free space in `/galy/home/biomonika/SMRTDATA`, but not that much in `userdata`.

After `ls` I see folder `userdata`. Now I am typing:

```
ln -s /galy/home/biomonika/SMRTDATA userdata
```

When I take a look with `ls -lah`, there are no arrows.
However, when I go inside `userdata`, I see this:

```
SMRTDATA -> /galaxy/home/biomonika/SMRTDATA
```

This is not correct, is it? I want arrow from `userdata -> /galy/home/biomonika/SMRTDATA` if I understand this correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the directory *first*.  Otherwise, `ln` will place the link in that directory -- as you just saw.

(i.e. `mv userdata userdata.local` then make your symlink)

Comment: Well, that's kind of weird behavior, but good to know! Thanks for such a quick and awesome answer.

Comment: It's consistent with every other UNIX command. `cp foo bar` where `bar` is a directory doesn't *replace* the directory with a file.  Even the `-f` option to `ln` will not destroy a directory.